# Python dict to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a set of data that can come through a stock data API, the amount of data and how stocks is depending on users' requests. The data I receive from the API comes in as a dictionary.

Example:

```
{'YAR':              last
 date             
 2020-07-10  336.4
 2020-07-13  344.0
 2020-07-14  344.3,
 'DNB':               last
 date              
 2020-07-10  129.60
 2020-07-13  142.45
 2020-07-14  145.50,
 'NHY':              last
 date             
 2020-07-10  27.35
 2020-07-13  28.56
 2020-07-14  28.50}
```

Is it possible to write a for loop in Python where for every key in the dictionary it will create a new pandas data frame row with its value and date as index?

So that the dataframe looks something like this?

[image: How I want the dataframe to look like]

I have tried something like this, where I called the dictionary the API provides dataToday:

```
tickerlist = ['YAR','DNB','NHY']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickerlist)

for ticker in tickerlist:
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataToday[ticker]))
```

But this gives me a data frame which looks like this:

[image: Dataframe my code creates]

I know it might be a stupid or a easy question, all ideas are appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Please update your question with a proper dict as the one posted is malformed and incomprehensible.

Comment: @Jab this the dictionary the API provided when I request data, unfortunately the API does not give me an option on how I want to receive the data. Anyhow, I have updated my question with some breakthrough.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not a json/dict, I assumed data is like

```
data_as_dict = {
'YAR': { 'date' : [ '2020-07-10',  '2020-07-13',  '2020-07-14'], 'last' : [336.4, 344.0, 344.3] },
'DNB': { 'date' : [ '2020-07-10',  '2020-07-13',  '2020-07-14'], 'last' : [129.60, 142.45, 145.50] },
'NHY': { 'date' : [ '2020-07-10',  '2020-07-13',  '2020-07-14'], 'last' : [27.35, 28.56, 28.50] }
}
```

Than with

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_sub_dfs = []

for stock_dict in data_as_dict:
    sub_class = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_as_dict[stock_dict], orient="columns")
    sub_class.set_index('date')
    sub_class.columns = [stock_dict]
    
    list_of_sub_dfs.append(sub_class)
```

It might be done prettier without a loop, but can't think of a obvious way to do so.

Use for instance..

```
pd.concat(list_of_sub_dfs,axis=1)
```

to concatenate them to:

```
              YAR     DNB    NHY
date                            
2020-07-10  336.4  129.60  27.35
2020-07-13  344.0  142.45  28.56
2020-07-14  344.3  145.50  28.50
```